# Relative and demonstrative pronouns "that" and "those"

Tags: grammar, that

I think the sentence

> the difference between the behaviour of young people today and *that* of *those* in the past

is correct, as *that* (relative pronoun) replaces *behaviour* and *those* (demonstrative pronoun) refers to *young people*.

Can we also say:

> the difference between the behaviour of young people today and the one of yesterday (or and the one of youth in the past)

Can you help me explain why the first one is correct. I can't quite construct the argument, but I know the first example is correct, whilst I'm not sure the second example (using *one* instead of *that* to refer to the behaviour) is correct in this case.

Comment: 'Behaviour' is uncountable so you can't use 'one'.

Comment: That seems to nail it, @Dan. Do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: You don't need to re-specify either (although it requires a different preposition): "the difference in the behaviour of young people today and in the past", or "...today compared to the past..."

Comment: Why do you consider _that_ here to be a relative pronoun?

Comment: @AndrewLeach You could just leave out 'that' as well. "...behaviour of young people today and of those of the past" sounds fine to me

Comment: Your first sentence is grammatically correct but it does not read smoothly.

Comment: @Dan: That's true, but it's not the whole story. \*"The flag of Japan is simpler than the one of Mexico" still sounds bad, even though *flag* is countable.

Comment: @ruakh - I agree that your example sounds bad, but this is not for the reasons discussed here.  It's simply inelegant :-)

Answer (score -1):

In your sentence, 'that' is a pronoun all right (it replaces 'the behaviour'), but NOT a relative pronoun, and not a demonstrative pronoun either!

On the other hand, 'those' actually is a demonstrative pronoun replacing 'the young people'. The reason it is 'those' rather than 'these' is to do with the remoteness implied by 'in the past' as opposed to the closeness of 'today'.

But as Andrew Leach suggests in his comment you can just leave out 'that of those' completely and write 'the difference between the behaviour of young people today and in the past'… same meaning, fewer words, more efficiency!

And, as Dan says in his comment, 'behaviour' is uncountable, so you can't use 'the one' instead of 'that'.

Comment: How is _that_ not a demonstrative pronoun here? What else would you call it?